# HTML/CSS Div tag alignment issue in pop-up

Tags: html, css

I've been struggling with div alignments for a while. I have one pop-up in which I have 4 inline-block divs. Now when all of them have no content, the alignment seems to be fine. But as soon as I add some input button tags in one of the div, that particular div goes off alignment.

Here is HTML/CSS in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3LN7/2/)

Any suggestions on what's wrong with CSS. Thanks you.

Comment: Put any content in any div and the alignment is lost. Can I ask you why you seems to have put everything upside-down (negative margins)?

Comment: Is that HTML intended for tablets?

Comment: It's not for tablets. We already had some popup markup that I was reusing. The goal is to center the popup irrespective of window size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give .selectDiv "vertical-align:top;" and .vBtnBar "margin:10px;"

Comment: Thanks..!! You just saved my Saturday :-)